# Elasticsearch simple query string and highlighter leads to timeout

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing a strange problem with Elasticsearch:

I have this query which results in a timeout because it takes more than 60 seconds:

```
GET /website/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "mbs regex replace all",
      "fields": ["content_primary"],
        "default_operator": "and"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "content_primary": {}
    }
    ,"fragment_size" : 200
  }
}
```

There are 3 options to make the query work:

- Remove the highlight
- Change the default_operator to "OR"
- Remove the word "all" from the query term

If I remove the highlighter, the query finishes within 9 milliseconds.
If I search for "mbs regex replace" (without the word "all" and with highlight enabled and operator AND) it finishes within 166 milliseconds.
If I change the query operator to OR (with highlight enabled) it finishes within 11 milliseconds.

But for my application, I need all three parameters exactly like specified, because the query "mbs regex replace all" is coming from the user, I need the highlighter for the frontend and I need the operator to be AND, so the search works like the user expect it.

What is wrong here?

The index has 96743 documents.
Elasticsearch v7.11.2 hosted on cloud.elastic.co

Edit: this is the mapping:

```
PUT /website
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter" : {
        "custom_synonym" :  {
          "type" : "synonym",
          "lenient": true,
          "synonyms": [ "FM => FileMaker", "DDR => Datenbank Design Report", "DB => Datenbank", "TO, Table Occurence => Tabellenauftreten" ]
        },
        "german_stemming": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "german"
        },
        "german_stopping": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_german_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_german_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "custom_synonym"]
        }
      }
    }
  },  
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "authors" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "classifications" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "content_primary" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "german" : {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "custom_german_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        "date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "description" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "domain" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "keywords" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "language" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "properties" : {
          "properties" : {
            "Plugin Komponente" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "osversion" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "softwareversion" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "source" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            },
            "german" : {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "custom_german_analyzer"
            }
          }
        },
        "url" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "urlToImagePreview" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your mapping? Would be nice if you can also share query analyzer information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I added the mapping

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the default highlighter `unified` has a problem with long documents. I will switch to `plain` which is much faster (178 milliseconds instead of 60 seconds in my case).

Also, I think I will get rid of super long documents.

See discussion here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-simple-query-string-and-highlighter-leads-to-timeout/273897